# Converting .net created binary data to string using php

Tags: php, .net

I have a file with extension .log.They are using this code for converting date to bytes and write it in to a file.

```
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(this.EventDate), 0, data, 0, 8);
```

I need to retrieve the date back from the byte using PHP.

Comment: Of what type is this.EventDate?

Comment: that is current date and time

Comment: guessing mode: `long EventDate` [...] `this.EventDate = someDateTime.toBinary()`; ?

Comment: need to use PHP for converting

Comment: Yes, but you still haven't answered my initial question. The code you've posted references `this.EventDate`. Somewhere in the containing class this member variable is declared. We need to know the type of that variable (not a description like "current date and time") and how the value of this variable is set (that's most likely a line like `this.EventDate = ...`)